# Cannot replicate to Datanode in Hadoop while importing from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to import data from mysql table to hdfs. I am using the below sqoop import command

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee --username root --password *** --table Emp --m 1
```

I am getting the below error

```
16/05/07 20:01:18 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/parquet-format-2.0.0.jar
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:269)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:390)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:483)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:196)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:169)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:266)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:118)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

I have the parquet-format-2.0.0.jar at usr/lib/sqoop folder, but even then it showing the error.

I tried to import all the sqoop lib to the hdfs but then i can do that its throwing the below error

> 16/05/07 18:40:11 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/xz-1.0.jar.*COPYING* could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1549)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3200)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:641)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at

What can do now? I can't copy the jar files to the HDFS and also I can't import the data to HDFS form MySQL.

I tried this solution
[sqoop import eror - File does not exist:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892968/sqoop-import-eror-file-does-not-exis)

but can't proceed from the second step. I also cleared the cache and restarted the Hadoop file system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For datanode replication error, following may be the reasons:

```
Datanodes doesn’t have enough disk space to store the blocks

Namenode can not reach Datanode(s) or Datanode(s) could be down/unavailable
```

Make sure the connectivity between Namenode  and Datanode(s) and also the Datanode(s) have sufficient space to store the new blocks.

In case, if there is enough disk space, you need to reformat your nameNode.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode: namenode clusterID = CID-c5c99144-3198-443a-8af0-cd3e3407f706;      I am getting this error in the datanode log.